# Leaving target processor paused nios ii multiprocessor application

Tags: embedded, design, c, vhdl, intel-fpga

I m using the multiprocessor tutorial, to have a MPSOC application, but when i finish all steps and running the nios application 
I have this message in the terminal,

```
Using cable "USB-Blaster [USB-0]", device 1, instance 0x00
Processor is already paused
Reading System ID at address 0x0960A190: verified
Initializing CPU cache (if present)
OK
Downloading 07000000 ( 0%)
Downloaded 61KB in 1.0s (61.0KB/s)
Verifying 07000000 ( 0%)
Verified OK 
Leaving target processor paused
```

I have done this work many times but with the some error, 
please can any one help me, I m using quartus 9.0 and a de2_70 board thinks wery much.

Comment: Quartus 9.0 is very old. Current version is 12.1 SP1.

Comment: I agree with Leon. Quartus is known to have many many issues, although sometimes old issues that were fixed pop up in new versions, a la whack a mole.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem is the version of quartus because it works well for simple design (1 cpu). thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are a couple of issues that could be a problem:

1. The CPU is being held in reset due to some other peripheral not correctly starting up.
2. There is a software error launching the debugger software. I don't think it's this because you mention this software has worked before.

It's most likely that it's #1 - one of your CPUs is being held in reset (or both) due to (for example,) the PLL not locking or something else is not coming up correctly.

It's probably best to check what the CPUs are dependant on to come out of reset and ensure that those are all starting up correctly.

Since you mention that this works for single processor designs, double check that your CPU resets are all connected correctly according to this [multi-processor tutorial](http://www.altera.com/literature/tt/tt_nios2_multiprocessor_tutorial.pdf),   see table 1-3 and onwards, from page 1-23.

Comment: I had apply all steps on the tutorial with the some standard that I had used for single processor and with all connection in the matrix in sopc builder